# What is called a jump tap in Android documentation?

Tags: android, touch

I was looking through [ViewConfiguration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html) class documentation and I found `getJumpTapTimeout()` method. Description says it is used to determine whether user wants to perform a "jump" tap or a regular one. The user has to complete jump tap within this time or it will be a regular one. The question is what is this jump tap anyway?

I've looked through the source, but it doesn't give any clues. Jump tap timeout is 500 ms, so is the long press timeout. So if I keep my finger for more than 500 ms on the same spot without moving, this is a long press, and it's not a tap. Tap timeout is 115 ms, so I have to at least not move my finger for this time or this won't be a tap. But then I have to do something until my 500 ms expire. Only what exactly?

Comment: It's for the upcoming Android-powered Dance Dance Revolution systems. :-)

Comment: @CommonsWare Maybe. :) It's been there since the first version of Android, and it appears it isn't used by the platform itself at all.

Comment: Should be filter for unintended taps, when finger jump on screen as user touches/moves around.

Comment: @LubosHoracek Good guess, that might actually be it!

Answer (score 1):

It is same as tap applied to active page elements, but used in earlier versions of webview, now this parameter is simply redefined inside webview as tap_timeout, now it sess to be used only for dpads

```
    // This should be ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()
    // But system time out is 100ms, which is too short for the browser.
    // In the browser, if it switches out of tap too soon, jump tap won't work.
    // In addition, a double tap on a trackpad will always have a duration of
    // 300ms, so this value must be at least that (otherwise we will timeout the
    // first tap and convert it to a long press).
```

Answer (score 1):

I have seen its usage in one of Google's open source project [Eyes-Free Android Applications](https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/) more specifically inside [ProcessorFocusAndSingleTap.java](https://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/source/browse/trunk/accessibilityServices/talkback/src/com/google/android/marvin/talkback/ProcessorFocusAndSingleTap.java) Inside `performClick(AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat node)`

For clarity I am mentioning here what It was used for

If a user quickly touch explores a content i.e, (event stream < ViewConfiguration.getTapTimeout()), then to avoid sending an unintentional ACTION_CLICK they have Switched off clicking on content.

Basically , `It's The timeout after which an event is no longer considered a tap`

Comment: So after each tap the web view is disabled for 500 ms, is that what it is? And if the user does a tap during this time frame, it is a jump tap?

Answer (score 0):

you jump from one app to the other. Jump will tell your phone that you jumped and will no longer keep the previous app on.

Comment: What does it have to do with taps and timeouts, though?